# LDAP authentication configurations for WAS Liberty Profile 8.5.5

Tags: ldap, lotus-domino, websphere-liberty

I'm working on configuring the LDAP authentication for user login worklight console and app center. The WL server is running on top of WAS Liberty Profile 8.5.5. The configuration is some kind working, but still not as expected.

Before starting with my questions, let me describe the client's LDAP env which is a little complex. They have a Domino server and a Active Directory server. In Domino, the User node appears as for example [CN=Apple Pie,OU=AU,O=Hello] and it has UID as [APie]. I believe Active Directory is authenticated against UID[APie]. The interesting thing is they have different password in Domino and AD. Domino is configured to accept both pure UID[APie] and pure CN[Apple Pie] with password from either Domino or AD. But if you login as [CN=Apple Pie,OU=AU,O=Hello], then only the domino password works.

Now the issue with Liberty is that with below configuration, when I login with UID[APie], it will get [CN=Apple Pie,OU=AU,O=Hello] from Domino and use it for authentication. In that case, I can only use the password for Domino.

```
[12/11/14 14:29:18:773 EST] 0000006f id=c1759c56 ws.security.credentials.wscred.internal.WSCredentialProvider > setCredential Entry  
                                                                                                               Subject:
    Principal: WSPrincipal:APie
    Private Credential: {user.registry.authenticated.userid=CN=Apple Pie,OU=AU,O=Hello}
    Private Credential: com.ibm.ws.security.token.internal.SingleSignonTokenImpl@87d8c005
```

My question is how I can change the configuration of ldapRegistry to let it authenticate against pure UID?

```
<ldapRegistry id="ldap" 
                  host="MMMMM" 
                  port="389" 
                  ignoreCase="true" 
                  baseDN="OU=AU,O=Hello" 
                  ldapType="IBM Lotus Domino" 
                  sslEnabled="false" >
            <domino50Filters
                        userFilter="(&amp;(uid=%v)(objectclass=inetOrgPerson))" 
                        groupFilter="(&amp;(cn=%v)(objectclass=groupOfNames))" 
                        userIdMap="*:uid" 
                        groupIdMap="*:cn" 
                        groupMemberIdMap="groupOfNames:member" >
            </domino50Filters>
    </ldapRegistry>
```

Comment: So maybe you should point to AD instead of Domino, if they use both.

Answer (score 0):

You have to ask the IBM WebSphere support team since it concerns Liberty LDAP registry configuration and not directly Worklight that leverages the application server user registry. The LDAP env is complex and I'm not sure that you can configure it with the LDAPRegistry.